# In 'grep' - Why does it behave this way?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

File `still` contains:

```
a
b
c
d
```

And

```
grep -v -e "a" -e "d" still
```

gives:

```
b
c
```

which is expected.

Now, file `fill` contains:

```
a,b,c,d
```

My command

```
grep -v -e "a" -e "d" fill
```

I expected it to give me `,b,c,`. But, I get no output. Why ?

Comment: grep prints matching lines. In case of -v it prints the lines that don't match. It does not break a line into fields separated by commas and apply the match/no-match rules on the fields. Does that help?

Comment: grep reads each line of the file and find a pattern. If you are vetoing a pattern, it will not show the whole line if pattern is found

Comment: This seems to be the case here - I came, I had nothing to do and no value to add. So, I downvoted ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your first example should give :

```
b
c
```

not

```
b
d
```

because you have `-v`

your 2nd attempt gave nothing, because grep does match line-wise. if the whole line doesn't match, the line won't be in output.

if you want to remove `a and d` in your 2nd example, you could use sed:

```
kent$  echo "a,b,c,d"|sed 's/[ad]//g'
,b,c,
```

Comment: @blasto what does `>>>` mean?

Answer (score 4):

From `grep` [man page:](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

> grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern

Or in other words:

> grep  searches  the  named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.By default, grep prints the matching lines.

In your second example your file only contains one line, which doesn't match the inversed pattern. So nothing is printed.

---

What you can do in the second case is to use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), to cut your line then eventually do something with it.

**Edit**

As suggested by @Kent, using sed for your second case is better and more powerful than simply cutting, printing, and then grepping or doing something else to match.

Comment: I don't think `cut` is the right tool to handle the 2nd case. cut is field based, it doesn't do pattern matching. if I remembered it correctly. If you don't know the given input is `a,b,c,d` or `b,c,a,d` or `a,d,c,b`... how do you `cut`?

Comment: You cut, print, then grep :) But you answer using sed is better for this case. My answer is focused on why grep is not the right tool to do this.